`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17
I recently migrated from Visual Studio Code to WebStorm and I am facing some issues when I try to run the devcontainer on the WebStorm.
I open the devcontainer.json file and click on the small cube inside the file and select the second option, which is "Create Dev Container and Mount Sources...", then I select WebStorm.
These are the logs that I have once I click on the WebStorm option:
WARN[0000] /Users/gouvea/www/vtal/vtal-api/docker-compose.yaml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
WARN[0000] /Users/gouvea/www/vtal/vtal-api/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
[+] Building 0.2s (7/7) FINISHED                                                                        docker:default
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 163B                                                                              0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20.5.1-slim                                           0.0s
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [app 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:20.5.1-slim                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [app 2/2] WORKDIR /home/node/app                                                                       0.0s
 => [app] exporting to image                                                                                      0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                           0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:ab9f0263bedceecf977b16a0200119f2114dd2c537eaed453025d2b4d076fe57                      0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/vtal-api-app                                                                   0.0s
 => [app] resolving provenance for metadata file                                                                  0.0s
Setting up container features:
Downloading common-utils feature manifest…
Creating directory /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/NOTES.md
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/README.md
Creating directory /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/bin
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/devcontainer-feature.json
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/install.sh
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/main.sh
Creating directory /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/scripts
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/bin/code
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/bin/devcontainer-info
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/bin/systemctl
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/scripts/bash_theme_snippet.sh
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/scripts/devcontainers.zsh-theme
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/common-utils/scripts/rc_snippet.sh
Downloading zsh-plugins feature manifest…
Creating directory /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers-contrib/features/zsh-plugins
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers-contrib/features/zsh-plugins/README.md
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers-contrib/features/zsh-plugins/devcontainer-feature.json
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers-contrib/features/zsh-plugins/install.sh
Downloading shell-history feature manifest…
Creating directory /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/stuartleeks/dev-container-features/shell-history
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/stuartleeks/dev-container-features/shell-history/NOTES.md
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/stuartleeks/dev-container-features/shell-history/README.md
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/stuartleeks/dev-container-features/shell-history/devcontainer-feature.json
Writing file /Users/gouvea/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/stuartleeks/dev-container-features/shell-history/install.sh
Creating jb-devcontainer-features-7d8c863c532440ab478baabf115af092…
[+] Building 0.2s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                        docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.features                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 132B                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 50.22kB                                                                              0.0s
 => [1/1] COPY . /tmp/jb-devcontainer-features                                                                    0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                            0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                           0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:a43cff8ae2c2fedf56a3d03b780d517224e4d8c18325bac0d5d0489732a9778f                      0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/jb-devcontainer-features-7d8c863c532440ab478baabf115af092                      0.0s
WARN[0000] /Users/gouvea/www/vtal/vtal-api/docker-compose.yaml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
WARN[0000] /Users/gouvea/www/vtal/vtal-api/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
[+] Running 1/1
 ! app Warning pull access denied for jb-devcontainer-b2661c53ef1cb9890fb2f98e742a488c, repositor...              2.9s 
[+] Building 0.1s (1/1) FINISHED                                                                        docker:default
 => [app internal] load build definition from .features.temp.dockerfile                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                0.0s
failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open .features.temp.dockerfile: no such file or directory
WARN[0000] /Users/gouvea/www/vtal/vtal-api/docker-compose.yaml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
WARN[0000] /Users/gouvea/www/vtal/vtal-api/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container vtal-postgres  Started                                                                               0.2s 
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17

I really cannot understand why this is ALWAYS failing. I tried changing some things inside the Dockerfile but I always have the same result...
This is my devcontainer.json:
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/docker-existing-docker-compose
{
    "name": "vtal api",
    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../docker-compose.yaml",
        "docker-compose.yml"
    ],
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/home/node/app",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils:2": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/zsh-plugins:0": {
            "plugins": "git git-flow F-Sy-H zsh-autosuggestions zsh-completions",
            "omzPlugins": "https://github.com/z-shell/F-Sy-H https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions"
        },
        "ghcr.io/stuartleeks/dev-container-features/shell-history:0": {}
    },
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
            ]
        }
    }
}

This is the docker-compose.yml that I have inside the devcontainer folder (at the same level of the devcontainer.json file):
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app:cached

At the root folder, I have this docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: my-api
    command: ./.docker/start.sh
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app

  postgres:
    container_name: my-postgres
    image: bitnami/postgresql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysupersecret
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/pg:/data/postgres

And, the last but not important, the Dockerfile:
FROM node:20.5.1-slim

USER node

WORKDIR /home/node/app

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]


Does it work without features? I couldn't add them either in my IDEA Ultimate. Seems like Jetbrains bug.

Try putting docker-compose.yaml file(s) near by devcontainer.json.
Seems like an issue with Jetbrains IDEs.
